# How can I pass a method from different class to another class in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods, import, package

There are two files named:

1. *AnnuityDueGUI.java*
2. *AnnuityDueResultGUI.java*

Under *AnnuityDueGUI.java*, there is this method as below:

---

```
public double calculateFADGUI() {
        //FVA = A{[(1+i)^n – 1] / i} (1+i)
        String amountStr = amount.getText();  // Convert string to double
        dAmount = Double.parseDouble(amountStr);
        String iStr = iText.getText();
        dInterest = Double.parseDouble(iStr);
        String periodStr = period.getText();
        dPeriod = Double.parseDouble(periodStr);
        iPeriod = (int)dPeriod;
        due = new Annuity(dAmount, dInterest, iPeriod);
        System.out.println(due.calculateFAD());
        return due.calculateFAD();   //calculateFAD() is under Annuity.java
    }
```

---

Under AnnuityDueResultGUI.java, how can I grab the result from the method that I've stated above? Both classes are under the same package "GUI". I also did `import AnnuityDueGUI.* ;`

But still I don't have any idea on how to grab the result from *AnnuityDueGUI.java* and display it under *AnnuityDueResultGUI.java*.

Answer (score 6):

You will need a reference to the AnnuityDueGUI object in AnnuityDueResultGUI. So for instance

```
AnnuityDueGUI adg = new AnnuityDueGUI()
double result = adg.calculateFADGUI()
```

**UPDATE**:

Also if you happen to already be constructing the AnnuityDueGUI somewhere else you can just pass the reference to AnnuityDueResultGUI

```
public AnnuityDueResultGui(AnnuityDueGUI adg) {
    this.adg = adg;
}

private void otherFunc () {
    double results = this.adg.calculateFADGUI()
}
```

Comment: exactly what I'm answering...I need to be faster ;)

Comment: I'm not sure where the amount variable is stored, but if it is not part of AnnuityDueGUI, then consider making calculateFADGUI static and passing in amount.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AnnuityDueGUI {

public double calculateFADGUI(){
        //FVA = A{[(1+i)^n – 1] / i} (1+i)
        String amountStr = amount.getText() ;  //convert string to double
        dAmount = Double.parseDouble(amountStr) ;
        String iStr = iText.getText() ;
        dInterest = Double.parseDouble(iStr) ;
        String periodStr = period.getText() ;
        dPeriod = Double.parseDouble(periodStr) ;
        iPeriod = (int)dPeriod ;
        due = new Annuity(dAmount, dInterest, iPeriod) ;
        System.out.println(due.calculateFAD()) ;
        return due.calculateFAD() ;   //calculateFAD() is under Annuity.java
    }

//...other code
}

class AnnuityDueResultGUI {

AnnuityDueGUI var = new AnnuityDueGUI();
double result = var.calculateFADGUI();
//other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `AnnuityDueResultGUI` with a reference to the actual `AnnuityDueGUI` instance, then you can access the method:

```
public class AnnuityDueResultGUI {
  private AnnuityDueGUI parent;

  public AnnuityDueResultGUI(AnnuityDueGUI parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  public void somemethod() {
    parent.calculateFADGUI();  // now you can access a method from a AnnuityDueGUI  instance
  }
}
```

and somewhere inside a method of `AnnuityDueGUI`:

```
// ...
AnnuityDueResultGUI resultGUI = new AnnuityDueResultGUI(this);
// ...
```