# The method is undefined for the type - importing from other class

Tags: java, class, methods

I don't know how to import method from other class

Error: The method SitoEratostenesa(int) is undefined for the type SitoEratostenesaTest

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441483), but my functions are static and a problem occurs.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class SitoEratostenesaTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, x;
        int ilosc=args.length;
        int[] liczby = new int[ilosc-1];
        Arrays.fill(liczby, 0);

        for(i=1; i<ilosc; i++){
            liczby[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        for(i=2, x=1; i<args.length; i++){
            if(liczby[x]<liczby[i]){
                    x=i;
            }
        }

        SitoEratostenesa(liczby[x]);
    }
}
```

Second class starts with:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class SitoEratostenesa{
    public SitoEratostenesa(int n){
    boolean[] tab = new boolean[n-1];
    //and tab[] gets filled
```

The main purpose of importing things to SitoEratostenesaTest is to get tab[] in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `new SitoEratostenesa(liczby[x]);`

---

```
SitoEratostenesa(liczby[x]);
```

This trys to call a function called `SitoEratostenesa` in class `SitoEratostenesaTest`, which ofcourse, doesnt exist, and is the error you see.

I expect what you want to do is call the constructor of `SitoEratostenesa`, for which you need to create an object of that type, thus you would do

```
new SitoEratostenesa(liczby[x]);
^^^
```

But if you want to get access to the object that was just created, you need to store a reference to it, so you should do

```
SitoEratostenesa myObj = new SitoEratostenesa(liczby[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `@SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")` as Annotations.
To know more see [SuppressWarnings](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html)